# Dataframe turns empty after writing to mount

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a dataframe called updatesDF as follows,

```
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
|PartyID|      TIN|SourceSystemID|      ODSInsertDate|     ODSInsertBy|      ODSUpdateDate|     ODSUpdateBy|
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 11111|222222222|             1|2021-07-20 01:56:25|sneha|2021-07-20 01:56:25|sneha|
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------
```

so updatesDF.show() gives me the above output. Now I need to write this dataframe to a mount path,

```
updatesDF.write.format('delta').mode('append').save('/mnt/Sneha/Updates/')
```

So as soon as I write into this location, the updatesDF turns blank like this

```
+-------+---+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|PartyID|TIN|SourceSystemID|ODSInsertDate|ODSInsertBy|ODSUpdateDate|ODSUpdateBy|
+-------+---+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
+-------+---+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

There are no other steps in between and I also tried taking backup of this DF...both backup and original DF turns empty after the append step. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by turns blank? How did you check the empty dataframe?

Comment: @Koiralo : i did an updatesDF.show() before and after writing to the mount location.. before shows the updatesDF value but after shows empty dataframe.. There are no steps in between

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird situation. Looks like a memory saturation.

Can you try `updatesDF.persist()` or `.cache()` just after creation.

Comment: yes Tried all that, but still it empty.. So I am trying to write the DF to a table before loading to the path and then getting the data from table again.. Not sure why this is happening